# Buying appointments in German embassy in Tehran, Iran

Tags: germany, iran, embassies, tehran

I need an appointment for legalization of documents (not visa!) in the German embassy in Tehran. For a normal human it is almost impossible to book an appointment there, because the booking page is available for less than one minute per day, and if you get there, you may be to slow and all the waiting was in vain.

But you can buy the appointments from some people for ca. 100 dollars. I don’t know how they do it, but I think they have some technical solution, like automating the entering of data and checking if the booking system is open. Lots of people suspect that there is some kind of corruption in the embassy, but honestly I can’t think about that in the German(!) embassy, as the Germans are known to be very bureaucratic and correct.

I have two questions:

- How do those appointment sellers do it? Then I could do it for myself the same way.
- Do you have experience with buying that appointments? I know that it is really successful for most of the customers but more information would be nice.

Comment: I don't see how this is a travel question.

Comment: @Airsick, it is about dealing with the appointment system of the German embassy. Seems on topic for me.

Comment: Corruption does happen in Germany, but not $100 from a random guy on the street. That's too risky for the officials. Corruption in Germany is more likely a supplier slipping something worth $10,000 or more to a purchasing official.

Comment: @o.m. If this related to travel documents then maybe but the OP has specifically excluded that so it becomes 'How do I get an appointment at <specify government office here>'. Does ' I need an appointment to get my tax documents notarised' fall within the scope?

Comment: I need those documents to apply for travel documents in the second step and already applied for an appointment for the visa. I need the other documents in that visa appointment.

Comment: @o.m. "How do those appointment sellers do it?" is absolutely not a travel question. "Do you have experience with buying [these] appointments?" is a survey and not an objectively answerable question.

Comment: All German embassies use a central server farm hosted by the German Foreign Affairs office in Germany. Individual embassy officials or their staff aren't involved. The most likely reason you cannot access their appointment booking system is Iran's internet censorship is overblocking it. What these people selling you appointments do is circumventing Iran's internet censorship some way e.g. by using a satellite connection.

Comment: @janka: I was in Germany at the moment so that couldn't be the problem. But it worked out finally some days ago, but from Iran, not from Germany. I still think the sellers use a script to check the website all the time and enter their customer's data automatically.